# ng2-fancy-image-uploader not working in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

i have upgrade my project to angular 8 from angular 5 everything is working fine but ng2-fancy-image-uploader not working when open any page having `<fancy-image-uploader [options]="thumbnailOptions" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"></fancy-image-uploader>` it give me error like [image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/ogix/ng2-fancy-image-uploader/issues/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version called ngx-image-uploader for Angular 6+

https://github.com/ogix/ngx-image-uploader

Comment: i have installed this plugin but when i upload image it give me error. ImageUploaderComponent.html:61 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnailResizeMode' of undefined